# Sql Query: co-occurrence of column values

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table like this:

```
col1     col2
id1      item1
id1      item2
id1      item3
id2      item1
id2      item4
id3      item2
id3      item3
```

I have to run a query on this table to find the number of times each pair of `items` shared a common `id`. For ex, in the above case, the pair `(item1, item2)` has a count of `1` (only id1 has both item1 and item2). Similarly, the pair `(item2, item3)` has a count of  `2` (id1, id3).

I can write code to achieve this, but I am not able to come with a sql query. Help me write an efficient query to output the following:

```
col1    col2    count   
item1   item2    1
item1   item3    1
item1   item4    1
item2   item3    2
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Hive or MySQL?  Please tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: Hive or MySQL? Please tag the question correctly

Comment: Edited. I need to do this in Hive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select    t1.col2  as item_A
         ,t2.col2  as item_B
         ,count(*) as cnt

from                mytable t1 
          join      mytable t2
          on        t1.col1 = t2.col1

where     t1.col2 < t2.col2

group by  t1.col2
         ,t2.col2
```

---

```
+--------+--------+-----+
| item_a | item_b | cnt |
+--------+--------+-----+
| item1  | item2  |   1 |
| item1  | item3  |   1 |
| item1  | item4  |   1 |
| item2  | item3  |   2 |
+--------+--------+-----+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a self join:

```
select t1.col2, t2.col2, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.col1 = t2.col1
where t1.col2 < t2.col2
group by t1.col2, t2.col2;
```

Comment: There is one issue with your query. It will return redundant pairs like (item1, item2) and (item2, item1).

Comment: @devj . . . That is easily resolved using `<` instead of `<>`.